# Verify that given expr is a general solution to a given ODE

Tags: differential-equations, algebraic-manipulation

As in the title, for example:

```
eq = y''[x] + 4 y[x] == 7;
sol = DSolveValue[{eq}, y[x], x]
```

> `7/4 + C[1] Cos[2 x] + C[2] Sin[2 x]`

Now, to verify that `sol` is a solution I can do something along:

```
eq /. y -> Function[x, Evaluate[sol]] // Simplify
```

> True

But that's true for any specific solution, e.g. `sol = Sin[2 x] + 7/4`.

I could find cases of symbols/constants and verify that there are `n` of them. But this is not enough because knowing that I could enter `sol = Sin[2 x] + 7/4 + C[1] + C[2]` so something more clever is needed.

Any ideas?

If your solution needs an assumption about a class of equations it applies to, so be it.

Comment: "If your solution needs an assumption about a class of equations" - I would only say that the linear case is likely to be much easier than the nonlinear one.

Comment: sol = Sin[2 x] + 7/4 + C[1] + C[2] is definitely no solution for C[i] different from zero. MMA gave you the most general one.

Comment: @J.M. yes, I think I don't need more at the moment.

Comment: @DanielHuber right, I had to leave quickly and didn't pay attention, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have in mind **linear** differential equation of *n*-th order, you have to check two things:

1. That `sol` is indeed a solution. That you did already.
2. That there are exactly *n* homogeneous solutions which are linearly independent.

The key here is linear independence. In order to detect the linear dependence between functions you can calculate [wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian)

So, the second point can be checked by, for example:

```
hsol = Coefficient[sol, Union[Cases[sol, _C, All]]];Length[hsol]
wro = FullSimplify[Det[NestList[D[#, x] &, hsol, Length[hsol] - 1]]]
```

When `sol=7/4 + C[1] Cos[2 x] + C[2] Sin[2 x]`, `Length[hsol]` evaluates to 2, and `wro` is nonzero.

When, e.g., `sol = (C[1] + C[2]) Sin[2 x] + 7/4`, `Length[hsol]` is again 2, but `wro` is zero.

**UPD**: Thanks to Michael E2 comment, it appears that there is a dedicated function for Wronskian, so the second line in my solution can be rewritten as

```
wro=Wronskian[hsol,x]
```

Comment: Have you seen [`Wronskian`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Wronskian.html)?

Comment: Can you  give a reference to the definition of a general solution  used by you, especially to "That there are exactly n homogeneous solutions which are linearly independent"? How these " n homogeneous solutions" are related to `sol`? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 Hmm, kind of my active knowledge. But why, just check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation

around of  "In the case of an ordinary differential operator of order n, Carathéodory's existence theorem "

Comment: @RomaLee: Sorry, you still don't answer "How these " n homogeneous solutions" are related to `sol`?".

Comment: @user64494 Just read my code: they are assumed to enter `sol` as linear combination with coefficients of the form `C[k]`.

Answer (score 2):

The complete solution space to a system of ODEs can have a complicated structure, including singular components (e.g. Clairaut equations) and multiple branches. Let us call a solution $y_{\bf C}$ a locally general solution to an ODE system with smooth coefficients of dimension $n$ at $(x,{\bf C})=(x_0,{\bf C}_0)$ to a system of ODEs if the mapping that maps a parameter vector ${\bf C} = (c_1,\,c_2,\dots,\,c_n)$ to a solution $y_{\bf C}$ has an injective derivative at $(x_0,{\bf C}_0)$.  If a solution to a linear ODE is locally general, then it is the general solution and, furthermore, it is the complete solution in that it represents all possible solutions.
Here's a not too well tested implementation of these ideas:

```
ClearAll[nLocallyInjective];
nLocallyInjective[eq_, sol_, {x_, x0_}, params_List -> p0_List] :=
  Module[{ivar, dim, dvars, ics, res, der},
   ivar = Flatten@{x};
   dim = Length@params;(* Check: Length@p0==dim+1 *)
   dvars = NestList[D[#, x] &, sol, dim - 1];
   der = D[dvars, {params}] /. 
     Thread[Join[ivar, params] -> Flatten@{x0, p0}];
   If[Precision[der] == MachinePrecision,
    res = Abs[First@Eigenvalues[der, -1]/
          Norm[der, Infinity]/$MachineEpsilon/Length@der] > 10,
    res = Simplify[Det[der] != 0]
    ];
   (* Alt: res=MatrixRank[der]==dim *)
   res
   ];

ClearAll[nLocallyGeneralSolution];
nLocallyGeneralSolution[eq_, sol_, y_, {x_, x0_}, p0_List] :=
  Module[{ivar, dvar, dorder, params, dvars, ics, res, der},
   ivar = Flatten@{x};
   dvar = Flatten@{y};
   dorder = Total[Internal`ProcessEquations`DifferentialOrder[{eq},
      ivar, dvar], Infinity];
   (* check dimensions *)
   params = Union@Cases[sol, _C, Infinity];
   res = Length[params] == dorder;
   (* check sol is a solution *)
   res = res && FullSimplify[
     Flatten@{eq} /. 
       Thread[dvar -> (Function @@ {ivar, #} & /@ Flatten@{sol})] // 
      Apply[And]];
   (* check locally injective *)
   res = res && nLocallyInjective[eq, sol, {x, x0}, params -> p0]
   ];
```

Examples:

```
eq = y''[x] + 4 y[x] == 7;
sol = DSolveValue[{eq}, y[x], x];
nLocallyGeneralSolution[eq, sol, {y}, {x, 0}, {0, 0}]

(*  True  *)

eq = y''[x] + 4 y[x]^2 == 7;
sol = DSolveValue[{eq}, y[x], x];
nLocallyGeneralSolution[eq, sol, {y}, {x, 0}, N@{1, 1}]

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Can you give a reference to " Let us call a solution $y_{\bf C}$ a locally general solution at $(x,{\bf C})=(x_0,{\bf C}_0)$to a system of ODEs if the mapping that maps a parameter vector ${\bf C} = (c_1,\,c_2,\dots,\,c_n)$ to a solution   $y_{\bf C}$ has an injective derivative at $(x_0,{\bf C}_0)$"? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 It's an ad hoc def. See for instance V.I. Arnold's rectifiability theorem in his ODEs book.

Comment: " V.I. Arnold's rectifiability theorem in his ODEs book" is not a reference used by civilized people (no Chap, Par, and/or page). I will be waiting for a serious and solid reply of you. Your  "ad hoc" also does not make a good impression.

Comment: Unfortunately, your approach fails with `eq1 =x^2*y''[x]+x*y'[x]+(x^2-2^2)*y[x]==0;sol1 = DSolveValue[{eq1}, y[x], x];nLocallyGeneralSolution[eq1, sol1, {y}, {x, 0}, N@{1, 1}]`,whereas the approach from my answer works.

Comment: @user64494 The answer to your example should be failure (or `False`). If your method says it's locally general, then your method is wrong.  Quit wasting people's time with frivolous nonexamples.

Comment: Can you ground your claim  "The answer to your example should be failure (or False)". I am still waiting for an exact reference.

Comment: @user64494 The point you chose is not in the domain of the coefficients of the ODE.  Really, I don't have time to teach you basic analysis.

Comment: You are right: `nLocallyGeneralSolution[eq1, sol1, {y}, {x, 1}, N@{1, 1}]` performs `True`. The point `{x,0}` was my fault. The method from my answer also works well for $\{(x,y):x \neq 0\}$ in this case..

Answer (score 1):

According to [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/General_solution), in order to prove that `sol` from

```
eq = y''[x] + 4 y[x] == 7;sol = DSolveValue[{eq}, y[x], x]
```

is a general solution of `eq` one should prove that `sol` is a solution of `eq` for any `C[1]` and `C[2]` (done in the question) and  any Cauchy problem has a (unique) solution, more exactly,

```
ForAll[{x0, d1, d2},  Exists[{C[1],   C[2]}, (sol /. x -> x0) == d1 && 
(D[sol, x] /. x -> x0) == d2]];
```

Unfortunately,

```
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

fails since nonalgebraic equations are under its consideration. However, we can directly check it in such a way.

```
Solve[7/4+C[1] Cos[2 x0] + C[2] Sin[2 x0] == d1 && 
2 C[2] Cos[2 x0] - 2 C[1] Sin[2 x0] == d2, {C[1],C[2]}] // FullSimplify
```

> `{{C[1] -> 1/4 ((-7 + 4 d1) Cos[2 x0] - 2 d2 Sin[2 x0]),  C[2] -> 1/4 Cos[2 x0] (2 d2 + (-7 + 4 d1) Tan[2 x0])}}`

Note that the deteminant of the above system equals 1 and the singularities in `C[2]`, when `Tan[2x0]` does not exist, are removable.